# Run some code in React after multiple async useState setters

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a functional React component in which I am using `useState` to manage state.  Normally, it's just a form with two fields - `code` and `env` - which the user can manually fill out and submit.  However, when the component loads, I also want to check any querystring params and if the appropriate ones exist, I want to populate and submit the form automatically.  That way, users can bookmark specific form submissions.

The problem I'm having is that, as we all know, `useState` setters are async, just like `setState` in class components.  As both form fields are controlled by state, setting both values will kick off multiple renders, so where should I put the code to submit the form so that I'm guaranteed that both state updates have completed?

Here is the form:

[image: Form]

And here is a simplified, sanitized version of the code I have:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

import axios from "axios";
import queryString from "query-string";
import Form from "react-bootstrap/Form";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";
import ToggleButtonGroup from "react-bootstrap/ToggleButtonGroup";
import ToggleButton from "react-bootstrap/ToggleButton";
import Card from "react-bootstrap/Card";

/*
 * this component will show a spinner or the results from the API when complete
 */ 
const PortalDisplay = ({ data: portal, isLoading }) => {
  if (Object.keys(portal).length === 0 && !isLoading) {
    return null;
  } else if (isLoading) {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>loading&hellip;</p>
      </div>
    );
  } else if (!!portal.id && !isLoading) {
    return <div className="card-portal">data goes here</div>;
  }
};

/*
 * main component
 */     
const PortalConfiguration = () => {
  const [validated, setValidated] = useState(false);
  const [code, setCode] = useState("");
  const [env, setEnv] = useState("prod");
  const [portalInfo, setPortalInfo] = useState({});
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

  const params = queryString.parse(location.search);

  const onSubmitForm = (event) => {
    const form = event.currentTarget;
    setValidated(true);

    if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();
      return;
    }
    //re-initialize
    setIsLoading(true);
    setPortalInfo({});

    axios
      .get(`http://www.example.com/api`)
      .then((response) => {
        setIsLoading(false);
        setPortalInfo({ ...response.data, ...{ baseUrl: baseUrl[env] } });
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));

    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!!params && !!params.portal && !!params.env) {
      if (!/^[a-zA-Z]{3}$/.test(params.portal) || (params.env !== "prod" && params.env !== "demo")) {
        console.log(`Specified portal parameters {portal: ${params.portal}} and {env: ${params.env}} are incorrect`);
      } else {
        // this is where i want to set the portal and env states and submit the form
      }
    }
  }, [params.portal]);

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Your Portal Configuration</h1>

      <Card>
        <Card.Body>
          <Form noValidate validated={validated} inline className="form-portal" onSubmit={onSubmitForm}>
            <Form.Group className="form-group-code">
              <label className="sr-only" htmlFor="code">
                Portal Code
              </label>
              <Form.Control
                type="text"
                id="code"
                value={code}
                required
                placeholder="Enter Portal Code (e.g. 'FWU')"
                maxLength="3"
                onChange={(e) => setCode(e.target.value)}
              />
              <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">Portal Code must be three letters (a-z)</Form.Control.Feedback>
            </Form.Group>
            <Form.Group>
              <ToggleButtonGroup type="radio" name="env" value={env} onChange={(val) => setEnv(val)}>
                <ToggleButton type="radio" name="env" value="prod" variant="primary" className="btn-inline">
                  Production
                </ToggleButton>
                <ToggleButton type="radio" name="env" value="demo" variant="primary" className="btn-inline">
                  Demo
                </ToggleButton>
              </ToggleButtonGroup>
            </Form.Group>

            <Button variant="secondary" block="true" className="btn-inline" type="submit">
              Submit
            </Button>
          </Form>
        </Card.Body>
      </Card>
      <PortalDisplay data={portalInfo} isLoading={isLoading} env={env} />
    </>
  );
};
export default PortalConfiguration;
```

The line which is commented out and says "this is where i want to set the portal and env states and submit the form" is where I know I have querystring params passed and need to set both states, then submit the form.

FWIW, I have considered the usual answer to the question of how to deal with `useState`'s asynchronicity, which is to handle it in `useEffect`, scoped to the particular state variable you are interested in.  The two problems with that is that 1) I have two state variables that need to be updated so I don't think there's any guarantee that they will be updated in the order I called the setters, creating a possible race condition, and 2) I don't want to call this code every time that `code` or `env` updates, which can happen when the user manually interacts with the form.  I only want it to be auto-submitted when the component detects the querystring upon loading.

Comment: Would combining the two fields into something like `useState({code: '', env: 'prod`})` be an option?

Comment: The hook version, `useState` only works on one state variable at a time.  I guess I could refactor the whole thing into a class component which would make `setState` available, and you can set multiple states at once with that.  But you still run into the problem, when to submit the form to make sure state has been set successfully?